# Problem Regarding session in Springboot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, session-management

The problem I am facing is that ,when
I login the first user then the user gets logged in and a session is created ,but when I login second User, then first user gets converted into second one and session also gets replaced I. old session gets replaced with current Session ,What I want is that multiple users should be able to login at a time and should have their own unique session.

I tried the session Management in Springboot3 config file but nothing worked.

```
package com.springboot.Admin_Officer_Security_Temp.Config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;
import com.springboot.Admin_Officer_Security_Temp.Service.UserDetailsServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class UserConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthentic`enter code here`ationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**", "/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/Myprofile", "/Updateprofile", "/Adduser", "/Allusers", "/Dashboard").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/Dashboard")
                        .failureUrl("/login?error=true"))
                .logout(logout -> logout.invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID"))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher `enter code here`httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

This the config code

Comment: Login how? Are you using a single browser to login another user?

Comment: yes I am Using chrome and switching tabs on it

Comment: That won't work. You cannot use a single browser with cookies to a single website. The cookies are only valid for a single session. You need separate independent browsers (like one incognito or a totally different browser).

Comment: any other solution except different browsers

Comment: Not use sessions/cookies but use something else, like a header to store the session id, that way you can hold it in your javascript application (which is per tab) and send it with each request. Don't use a cookie as that is simply how cookies work, you can only have 1 for a certain URL/name combination in one browser session.

Comment: I had one more doubt regarding capturing photo and dynmically send it as a post method and accesing it on the controller side.